# Restore SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, ssms-2016

Experts,

I am new to sql server administration and have a question around restoring my old server instance.

I had the local sql express instance running on the version 13. The PC had broken down and had to replace the hard disk and fresh intall of windows 10 on it. However, I have the copy of the server directory which looks like J:\SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL (Backup, data, folders are right here).

As it was not a mission critical db, I did not go for backups. so backup directory is empty.

On the fresh disk, I have now installed the SSMS 2016 and tried to attach the db instance which was copied from older disk. However I could not find an easy way to attach the db. I ended up creating a new named instance.

How can I restore the instance that was copied from older disk? I want the old instance to act as a standalone instance. Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Copying is normally a poor way to create a backup, especially if the instance was still running and the database was attached when you copied the file (normally the file won't copy, due to locking, or will be corrupt). I would strongly suggest creating a backup on your old instance and using that. If you do, however, need to attach a file, it is all covered in the documentation: [Attach a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that SSMS 2016 isn't SQL Server. If you have only installed SSMS 2016, you haven't installed SQL Server. SSMS is an application, used to interact with SQL Server; where as SQL Server is a Service that runs on a host machine (the two don't even have to installed on the same machine).

Comment: As I mentioned on the original post, I had created an instance as well. Should I attach all user databases to the new instance? the document added in the first comment explains the process to attach individual databases to the instance. If I follow that, I will not be able to recover the system databases. Is there not an option to recover the entire instace (sys and user dbs)?

Comment: You should definitely should not be attaching system databases from other instances no; that is a recipe for disaster. It's far more recommended that you script out any resources you need from the old instance. You *can* restore a system database to a different instance, however, I also don't recommend it and it's not a simple task (especially with `master`) and requires specific conditions. If you need to move objects from your system databases across, script them out and then run the script on your new instance.

Comment: Thanks @Lamu. what information would I miss out if I attach just user dbs to the new instance? I thought sys dbs needs to have some info about user dbs like number and name of object stored within individual db. is it ok that I copy all the mdf & ldf files to the new instance?

Comment: It's not that you would "miss" out data if you attached them, it's just you would almost definitely break your new instance. I still don't understand why you are against a "normal" backup and restore process.

Comment: Thanks Lamu. I did not take the back up as it was just a play ground for me to learn few things. if you say sys dbs do not really matter during restore (of my kind), I dont mind missing them out.